# Which one suits better this case. zipWith or .map?

Tags: reactive-programming, spring-webflux, project-reactor

I have an external call to set some info in one `Mono` and I can solve it using either `.zipWith` or `.map` but I don't know which one should be more correct to use.

My method looks like this:

```
private Mono<Foo> callExtraInfo(Foo foo) {
    return  reactiveClient.getInfo()
             .map(info -> {
               foo.setInfo(info);
               return foo;
             });
```

But I think using `.zithWith` makes more sense to me cause adds to the original Mono the extra info instead:

```
private Mono<Foo> callExtraInfo(Foo foo) {
    return  reactiveClient.getInfo()
             .zipWith(Mono.Just(foo))
             .map(it -> {
               Foo result = it.getT2();
               result.setInfo(it.getT1());
               return result;
             });
```

I'd like to know some different opinions

Comment: `But I think using .zithWith in this scenario is better:` please motivate this statement

Answer (score 3, accepted):

given that the `Foo` object is readily available, the first solution is simpler and has less overhead (no extra `zip`, no extra creation of a `Tuple2`...) and is quite readable (arguably even more so than the second one) so I would go with that

Comment: Yes, I think you are right. Even though zipWith is meant for these situations, map in this case leaves the code more clean and readeable.